# how to create singleton class with arguments in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking for the right way to create a singleton class that accepts arguments in the first creation.
My research lead me to 3 different ways:

> **Metaclass**

```
class Singleton(type):
    instance = None
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls.instance is None:
            cls.instance = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls.instance

class ASingleton(metaclass=Singleton):
    pass
```

> **__new__**

```
class Singleton(object):
    instance = None
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls.instance is None:
            cls.instance = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls.instance
```

> **Decorator**

```
def Singleton(myClass):
    instances={}
    def getInstance(*args, **kwargs):
        if myClass not in instances:
            instances[myClass] = myClass(*args, **kwargs)
        return instances[myClass]
    return getInstance

@Singleton
class SingletonTest(object):
    pass
```

All of them work fine, but when it comes to initiation (like using **__init__** in normal class) I can't figure out the right way to implement it.
The only solution I can think about is using the metaclass method in this way:

```
class Singleton(type):
    instance = None

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls.instance is None:
            cls.instance = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls.instance

class ASingleton(metaclass=Singleton):
    def __init__(self,j):
        self.j=j
```

I don't know if this is the correct way to create singleton that accepts arguments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a singleton in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760685/creating-a-singleton-in-python)

Comment: that article was my main helpful tutorial, but as u can see, they didn't mention anything about "how to pass arguments or even how to setup the different methods) and that is my question

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've found out that the best way to implement Singleton is by using meta classes:

```
class Singleton (type):
    _instances = {}
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]

# Python 2
class MyClass():
    __metaclass__= Singleton

# Python 3
class MyClass(metaclass=Singleton):
     pass
```

Comment: I second this. I, too, think that metaclasses is the nicest way to implement a Singleton. However, have a look at metaclasses… I found them quite confusing in the beginning.

Comment: @Thomas sure, I cannot argue this ) Meta classes is tricky... But the Singleton is good use of it and is good start for understanding of metaclasses concept

Comment: True, Singleton's in Python actually made me understand Metaclasses :-)

Comment: what i understand from metaclass in singleton, it's like re-implement the method __call__() in the class that use "metaclass=singleton" to make sure to create one instance for that class.  it make sense if you think in the way that the actual singleton class is the one that use (metaclass=singleton),

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @AndriyIvaneyko's answer, here is a thread-safe metaclass singleton implementation:

```
# Based on tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance() approach.
# See https://github.com/facebook/tornado
# Whole idea for this metaclass is taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6798042/2402281
import threading

class ThreadSafeSingleton(type):
    _instances = {}
    _singleton_lock = threading.Lock()

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        # double-checked locking pattern (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking)
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            with cls._singleton_lock:
                if cls not in cls._instances:
                    cls._instances[cls] = super(ThreadSafeSingleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]

class YourImplementation(metaclass=ThreadSafeSingleton):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass  # your implementation goes here
```

Hope you find it useful!

Comment: you mean, this is will make sure to create only one instance by double check the value _instances by making the whole class as critical resource (semaphore approach)

Answer (score 2):

I think the solution proposed by @tahesse can raise a dead lock. If the `__init__` method contains another singleton than the lock won't be released.

Foe example :

```
class ThreadSafeSingleton(type):
    _instances = {}
    _singleton_lock = threading.Lock()

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        # double-checked locking pattern (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking)
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            with cls._singleton_lock:
                if cls not in cls._instances:
                    cls._instances[cls] = super(ThreadSafeSingleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]

class YourImplementation1(metaclass=ThreadSafeSingleton):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass  # your implementation goes here

    def simple_method(self):
        return "this is a test"

class YourImplementation2(metaclass=ThreadSafeSingleton):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.your_implementation1 = YourImplementation1()
    def simple_method(self):
        print(self.your_implementation1.simple_method())
```

So I changed that solution a bit

```
class ThreadSafeSingleton(type):
    _instances = {}
    _singleton_locks: Dict[Any, threading.Lock] = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        # double-checked locking pattern (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking)
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            if cls not in cls._singleton_locks:
                cls._singleton_locks[cls] = threading.Lock()
            with cls._singleton_locks[cls]:
                if cls not in cls._instances:
                    cls._instances[cls] = super(ThreadSafeSingleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]

class YourImplementation1(metaclass=ThreadSafeSingleton):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass  # your implementation goes here

    def simple_method(self):
        return "this is a test"

class YourImplementation2(metaclass=ThreadSafeSingleton):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.your_implementation1 =YourImplementation1()
    def simple_method(self):
        print(self.your_implementation1.simple_method())
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. The idea is to hash the instance key by args and kwargs.

```
import inspect
import threading

lock = threading.Lock()
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}
    _init = {}

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        cls._init[cls] = dct.get('__init__', None)

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        init = cls._init[cls]
        if init is not None:
            args_list = list(args)
            for idx, arg in enumerate(args_list):
                args_list[idx] = str(arg)
            tmp_kwargs = {}
            for arg_key, arg_value in kwargs.items():
                tmp_kwargs[arg_key] = str(arg_value)
            key = (cls, frozenset(inspect.getcallargs(init, None, *args_list, **tmp_kwargs).items()))
        else:
            key = cls
        if key not in cls._instances:
            with lock:
                cls._instances[key] = super(SingletonArgs, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[key]

class YourImplementation(metaclass=Singleton):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass  # your implementation goes here
```

Comment: This is really great! it only has one problem which is: if B inherits A which has Singleton as its meta, initializing B will now also initialize A instead of accessing A's Singleton (via super())

Comment: Also notice this doesn't take default arguments into account

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer did not work for me. What I wanted was every time I created an object of the singleton, it should have the values I passed to the constructor on the respective attributes. I used the `__new__` method and in the `__init__` I used the `hasattr` method to make sure the attributes that I don't want changed after they have been set remain unchanged.

```
class MySingleton:
    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not isinstance(cls._instance, cls):
            cls._instance = super(MySingleton, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls._instance

    def __init__(self, somearg):
        self.somearg = somearg
        if not hasattr(self, 'common'):
            self.common = f'this should be set once: set at {datetime.now()}'

    obj1 = MySingleton('object 1')
    print(obj1.somearg, id(obj1), obj1.common)

    time.sleep(1)

    obj2 = MySingleton('object 2')
    print(obj2.somearg, id(obj2), obj2.common)
```